# Full Serialization in Worfklow 4.0

Tags: xml-serialization, workflow-foundation-4

I'm trying to serialize a workflow (using C#'s workflow 4.0) to retrieve the full workflow XAML and have hit a wall.

I've got an activity (myActivity) that I've created.  The contents of the xaml file that describes this activity is:

```
    <Activity mc:Ignorable="sap" x:Class="atest.MySuite" >
  <Sequence sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="222,501">
    <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
      <scg3:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
        <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
      </scg3:Dictionary>
    </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
    <Sequence DisplayName="First Sequence" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,99">
      <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
        <scg3:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
          <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
        </scg3:Dictionary>
      </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
    </Sequence>
    <Sequence DisplayName="Second Sequence" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,99">
      <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
        <scg3:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
          <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
        </scg3:Dictionary>
      </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
    </Sequence>
    <Sequence DisplayName="Third Sequence" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,99">
      <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
        <scg3:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
          <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
        </scg3:Dictionary>
      </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
    </Sequence>
  </Sequence>
</Activity>
```

Note that the sub sequences show up in the XAML.

When I go to serialize this activity, I use the code I found on MSDN:

```
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(somePath))
{
    sw.Write(a.Log.ToString());
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb);
    XamlWriter xw = ActivityXamlServices.CreateBuilderWriter(new XamlXmlWriter(tw, new XamlSchemaContext()));

    XamlServices.Save(xw, myActivity);
    string serializedActivity = sb.ToString();
}
```

But the string that comes out the other end is simply:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><MySuite xmlns="clr-namespace:atest;assembly=Wtf.Automation.atest" xmlns:sap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities/presentation" />
```

I've poked around on MSDN and on stackoverflow, but haven't found a way to retrive the *full* XAML of a custom activity (given an instance of that activity) like what I've described in my xaml file, not just this truncated version.

Does anyone know if there's a way?  Code samples and/or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is that `ActivityXamlServices.CreateBuilderWriter` works with `ActivityBuilder` instances.  Try

```
XamlServices.Save(xw, new ActivityBuilder { Implementation = myActivity });
```

Answer (score 0):

Serialize:

```
public static string ActivityToXaml(Activity activity)
{
    StringBuilder xaml = new StringBuilder();

    using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(xaml, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true, OmitXmlDeclaration = false, }))
    using (XamlWriter xamlWriter = new XamlXmlWriter(xmlWriter, new XamlSchemaContext()))
    using (XamlWriter xamlServicesWriter = ActivityXamlServices.CreateBuilderWriter(xamlWriter))
    {
        XamlServices.Save(xamlServicesWriter, new ActivityBuilder { Implementation = activity });
    }

    return xaml.ToString(); 
}
```

Deserialize:

```
public static Activity ActivityFromXaml(string activityXaml) 
{
    using (var reader = new StringReader(activityXaml))
    {
        return ActivityXamlServices.Load(reader);
    }
}
```